# t test in r giving wrong estimate of mean vs aggregate function

Tags: r

```
totaldata$Age2 <- ifelse(totaldata$Age<=50, 0, 1)

t.test(totaldata$concernsubscorehiv, totaldata$Age2,alternative='two.sided',na.rm=TRUE, conf.level=.95, paired=FALSE
```

This code yiels this result:
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:

```
totaldata$concernsubscorehiv and totaldata$Age2
t = 33.19, df = 127.42, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 3.370758 3.798164
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 4.336842  0.752381
```

As you can see the mean of group y is 0.752381

Then we I estimate the mean of each group using this:

```
aggregate(totaldata$concernsubscorehiv~totaldata$Age2,data=totaldata,mean)
```

This yields

```
totaldata$Age2 totaldata$concernsubscorehiv 
1              0        4.354286             
2              1        4.330612
```

As you can see the mean of group 0 is 4.354286 not 0.752381 as estimated by t test. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `t.test` correctly. `0.752381` is the fraction of people for which `age2` is 1. You are supplying a vector of your normal data, and a vector of zero and ones, when instead you want to split up the first vector based on the grouping in the second.

Consider the following:

```
out <- rnorm(10)*5+100
bin <- rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob=0.5)

mean(out)
[1] 101.9462
mean(bin)
[1] 0.4
```

From the `?t.test` helpfile, we know that `x` and `y` are:

> x a (non-empty) numeric vector of data values.
>
> y an optional (non-empty) numeric vector of data values.

So, by supplying both `out` and `bin`, I compare each vector to each other, which probably does not make much sense in this example. See:

```
t.test(out, bin)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  out and bin
t = 86.665, df = 9.3564, p-value = 6.521e-15
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  98.91092 104.18149
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 101.9462    0.4000
```

Here, you see that `t.test` correctly estimated the means for my two supplied vectors, as I have shown above. What you want to do is to split up the first vector based on whether or not the second is 0 or 1.

In my toy example, I can do this easily by writing:

```
t.test(out[which(bin==1)], out[which(bin==0)])

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  out[which(bin == 1)] and out[which(bin == 0)]
t = 0.34943, df = 5.1963, p-value = 0.7405
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -5.828182  7.686176
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 102.5036  101.5746
```

Here, these two means correspond exactly to

```
tapply(out, bin, mean)
       0        1 
101.5746 102.5036
```

Comment: Thanks. If I am comparing two variables that are both continuous using t.test(totaldata$necessitysubscorehiv, totaldata$necessitysubscorecot, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95, paired=TRUE) and my output is Paired t-test

data:  totaldata$necessitysubscorehiv and totaldata$necessitysubscorecot
t = 10.028, df = 96, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.841956 1.257529
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
               1.049742   is this this correct?